# How do I fix a sink that became slow to drain after pouring polyurethane down it?

Tags: plumbing, woodworking, sink, maintenance, polyurethane

## Situation and problem

My buddy has a woodworking shop which he graciously allowed me to use for a woodworking project. I am a total novice in these kinds of areas, which will be doubly clear in a moment.

After applying the last coat of polyurethane to the project, I had about 2 tablespoons of polyurethane left over in my cup I was pouring out of.

Being very unwise and uneducated, I poured about 2 tablespoons of polyurethane down the shop sink. (For those on metric, Google tells me 2 tablespoons is roughly 30 milliliters.)

Now the sink drains very slowly. I'm assuming this is because the poly solidified in the pipes and created a partially obstructed drain. That's just my newbie guess, maybe some different interaction happened.

## Additional details

I did an internet search before the cleanup stage to see what dissolves polyurethane. So I mixed the poly with some paint thinner before pouring it down the sink. (Later, I learned neither poly nor paint thinner should be poured down a sink.) In any case, it didn't seem to make a difference related to the blockage, as the sink still ended up draining very slow.

My buddy knows about all this. I'm just trying to get additional info so I can get this fixed for him and correct my mistake.

My buddy says that the water from his shop doesn't go directly to a city waistline. It goes to a sewage ejector pump that's in the shed outside. And this sewage ejector pump doesn't operate all the time.

One thing I've researched, but haven't tried yet, is using vinegar to dissolve any polyurethane blockage. It's safe to pour down drains, and supposedly vinegar dissolves poly. Though it might take a large volume or be a very slow unblocking process?

## Help appreciated!

Any insight into how I should proceed would be much, much appreciated. I certainly don't want to make things worse as I try to make them better.

Comment: How good of a buddy is your buddy ?

Comment: If you are lucky it is still in the P-trap, so take it out to check

Comment: What are the pipes made out of?  Two tablespoons not that much, would try using a snake.

Comment: He is a very good friend of many years. I can check the P-trap. I'm curious what the "worst case scenario" is and what's the "best case scenario" here.

Comment: @crip659 -- I asked my buddy what material his p-trap and pipes are made out of, in case he knows. I'll report back if he answers. Is a snake strong enough to get through hardened polyurethane? If so, maybe I just call a good plumber? I was worried this could be an unusual case that plumbers wouldn't necessarily know what to do with.

Comment: Snake would not be strong enough, but will locate the problem.  Think there might have been a partial clog in the pipes before that the polyurethane made worst.  Expect to replace the piece of plumbing where the clog is.  P-trap is a good guess, but a snake should locate the piece/section of pipe, and can have the piece handy to replace when taken it apart.

Comment: i had a glob on my counter for a few months, nothing would clean it. One day i had my steam cleaner out and tried it. It came right off. I would try slowly dumping boiling water down the drain to soften and melt the poly. If you can get steam in there, that might work even better...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start with (no, wait - buying your buddy a large quantity of the GOOD version [in your buddy's opinion] of something they like a lot, then...) removing the trap, assuming the trap is not one that has to be sawn out to be removed (I hate those, and I hate the people that put those in anywhere but underneath a concrete slab.) A nice normal trap is unscrew 2-3 slip joints with a bucket to catch the slop and get right to the guts.

At that point you may well find your major blockage, and be able to either remove it, or simply replace the whole trap if it's stuck to the trap  very badly. If you need to snake, better to start with the trap removed if possible, it takes one set of turns out of the start of the run.

Alternatively, just call in a plumber...